# MATLAB and OSM Web Wizard for SUMO

Tags: matlab, openstreetmap, sumo

I want to generate traffic in MATLAB with SUMO. For this, I use [an implementation of the TraCI interface for Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44805-traci4matlab). How can I use the trace file of the traffic I created from SUMO in Matlab? Where is the tracefile containing the location information of the vehicles kept?